# image display based on condition in Vs 2005 asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, html

I have used the below code to display image on top of the page. For condition1

```
div1.Visible = true;
div2.Visible = false;
```

For condition2,

```
div1.Visible = false;
div2.Visible = true;
```

and the code in the aspx page is like this.

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" style="padding-left: 110px;">
  <img src="~/images/Package-Summary.gif" alt="Package Summary" />          
</div>

<div id="div2" runat="server" style="padding-left: 110px;">
  <img src="~/images/Process-Billing.gif" alt="Process Billing" />          
</div>
```

Here it doesnot show me the image, instead shows an error box in that part!! What might be the reason!!!

Comment: I am Sorry.. Alt text is displayed! The where is the problem at?? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a relative path to the image:

```
<img src="../images/Process-Billing.gif" alt="Process Billing" />
```

Comment: If the image couldn't be found the alt text would just display not an error.

Comment: I am Sorry.. Thats what i meant!! alt text is displayed! Where is the problem at??

Comment: @Ash I don't think that is entirely correct.  IE6 displays both the image-not-found image and the alt text, and my Chrome displays only the image-not-found icon.

Comment: On my localhost(IE), it shows alt text and an error icon i guess(box with red X inside)

Comment: @Ram you need to specify the path in a relative manner.  If the page with the `<img>` element is located at Pages/SpecialPages/pagename.aspx, for example, the relative path to the image might be ../../images/Process-Billing.gif

Comment: Matthew, I checked that buddy! But everything looks perfect here, i am so helpless!

Comment: @Ram Two things: one, you are sure the image exists where you think it does, right?  Two: are you using Visual Studio?  If you are, if you delete and then retype the `src=`, VS should give you a list of items in the current folder.  If you scroll all the way down you should see `Pick URL...` and can use that to get the correct image path.

Comment: Yes Matthew, i did that. Unfortunately, it is the same old path!! :(

Answer (score 1):

Your images are using server-side paths, but they're not server-side controls.  The divs surrounding them are server-side controls, which doesn't affect the images.  Either convert the image controls to server-side or convert the paths to something the client can request (relative paths, ideally).

Answer (score 0):

Actually your images are not picking the right path as you are using server path at client side. If you want to use root-relative path you should use server side Image control to assign path.

You can use an Image server control and can just change its source but I do not know what you exactly want. But on client you use relative path not root-relative path. For root-relative path you have to use server image control.

see the article

[ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

so it should be

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" style="padding-left: 110px;">
  <img src="../images/Package-Summary.gif" alt="Package Summary" />          
</div>

<div id="div2" runat="server" style="padding-left: 110px;">
  <img src="../images/Process-Billing.gif" alt="Process Billing" />          
</div>
```

or where ever your image directory is you can go back to your image directory by just adding another "../" before path to go back to image directory.